# Shorter way to code in Python

Tags: python

I am Python beginner. Following code does exactly what i want. But it looks a little dump coz of three for loop. Can somebody show me smarter/shorter way to achieve it? may be a single function or parallelizing for loops.

```
def getWordListAndCounts(text):
  words = []  
  for t in text:
      for tt in t:
        for ttt in (re.split("\s+", str(tt))):
            words.append(str(ttt))
  return Counter(words) 

text = [['I like Apple' , 'I also like Google']]
getWordListAndCounts(text)
```

Comment: You could do it with one fewer loop if `text` was `['I like Apple' , 'I also like Google']` instead of `[['I like Apple' , 'I also like Google']]`. Why are you using double brackets, anyway?

Comment: Actually the Text come from another method >>

def get_texts(reviews, score):
  texts = [] 
  texts.append([r[0].lower() for r in reviews if r[1] == str(score)]) ; 
  return texts

Comment: You may get better results posting here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def getWordListAndCounts(text):
    return Counter(re.split('\s+', str([' '.join(x) for x in text][0])))

text = [['I like Apple' , 'I also like Google']]
print getWordListAndCounts(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove redundat list (it will reduce level in list comprehension):

Since there is not any necessity to store temporary result in list, generators are more preferable and efficient way.
Check this one-line approach:

```
text = ['I like Apple' , 'I also like Google']
print Counter(str(ttt) for t in text for ttt in (re.split("\s+", str(t))))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use meaningful variable names. t, tt and ttt can't help the code being readable.
   Why not use "for phrase in text" then "for word in phrase"?
2. Why are you using double encoded strings? Unless it is already in this format when you are reading it, I would suggest you not to do this.